# Light weight Java API for LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I would like to validate username and password for my new open source Java project using LDAP(Iplanet or Open DS), despite of validating against database.

Primary activities i would like to do are:
 1) Validate userName and password 
 2) Add a user or Group to directoy server
 3) Assigning a user to a Group.

Any light weight Java API, that provides quick learning curve.

Comment: I don't know what you call _lightweight_ but [Spring LDAP](http://www.springsource.org/ldap/) can do this job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a good experience with [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) . It is just a single jar , has a good documentation ,  very user-friendly API , and [a lot of advantages](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/advantages/index.php)  when compared to the JNDI .

I especially like its ORM framework which can easily map a LDAP record to a Java object .

Answer (score 4):

My first choice would be the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/). JNDI should not be used for new code for various reasons:

- The LDAP model used by JNDI is not clean, and not clear
- There are a number of software defects in JNDI, and a few constructs that make certain LDAP operations impossible
- JNDI is not fully compliant from an LDAP standard point of view
- JNDI uses a disconnected configuration architecture which makes JNDI difficult to use

The UnboundID LDAP SDK

- is cleaner than JNDI
- is clearer than JNDI
- has support for failover and load-balancing
- has support for localization
- makes the use of syntax and matching rules easy
- has a shorter learning curve, easier to use than JNDI
- supports asynchronous operations
- supports in-memory directory server, which can be useful in unit testing

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of that with JNDI:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html

If you use the tutorial pages, you'll see examples for each of the things you want to do:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/

There's a framework to make it even easier:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/18/ldaptemplate-java-ldap-made-simple.html

But I don't recommend it really, it's really a way to manage overhead if you're doing lots of JNDI projects, not a way to make a single project easier.  The overhead of doing JNDI is just a one-time thing, once you've got it set up you won't ever have to touch it again.  If you have any problems just post them here and we'll figure them out.  :)

-t.